# Turn Off Object Caching in Entity Framework CTP5

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5

I am having trouble figuring out something with the Entity Framework Code First stuff in CTP 5. It is doing caching of objects and I don't want it to. For example, I load a page (working with an ASP.NET MVC site) which loads an object. I then go change the database. I re-load the page and the changes are not reflected. If I kill the site and rerun it then it obviously re-fetches. How do I, either generally for a type, or even for a particular query, tell it to always go get a new copy. I think it might have something to do with MergeOption but I'm having trouble finding examples that work with CTP 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Okay, figured it out. The following will sometimes pull from the EF cache:

```
return (from m in _dataContext.Monkeys
        where m.MonkeyId == monkeyId
        select m).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can use AsNoTracking() to bypass the change tracking/caching stuff:

```
return (from m in _dataContext.Monkeys.AsNoTracking()
        where m.MonkeyId == monkeyId
        select m).FirstOrDefault();
```